# Maxima's acos() does not work well

Tags: maxima

Maxima5.27.0 gives me a result with argument `sqrt(3)/2`

```
acos(sqrt(3)/2);
%pi/6
```

This is good. However, with argument `3/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(6))` it gives up to compute even though the two arguments are equivalent.

Why and how to make it well?

Answer (score 3):

Maxima will not contract the roots unless you ask it to. 
You can do this:

`acos(3/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(6))); rootscontract(%);`

or this:

`acos(3/(sqrt(2)*sqrt(6))), rootscontract;`